# There were errors building the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

New to c#. Using .NET Framework 4.5.2 . Visual Studio 2015
I am simply following this example:

http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/calling-stored-procedure-with-output.html
when I try to "View it in Browser" it gives me an error without any explanation:

[image]

My .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


namespace adoDemo
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string SC = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SC))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spAddEmployee", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtEmployeeName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlGender.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtSalary.Text);

                SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
                outputParameter.ParameterName = "@EmployeeID";
                outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string EmpID = outputParameter.Value.ToString();
                lblMessage.text = "Employee ID = " + EmpID;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my aspx file: the only thing here is `unrecognized tag prefix or device filter asp` if I hoover my mouse on `asp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<table style="border: 1px solid black; font-family:Arial">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Employee Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>
            Gender
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            Salary
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>          
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

In design mode it looks like this:

[image]

In my project I have 3 Web Forms, but I only using `WebForm3`, where there are only warnings - not errors.
Here is the error output:

[image]

Comment: `.text` should be `.Text`,`c#` is  case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the convention is for properties to start with a capital letter.

Simply use:

```
 lblMessage.Text
```

Comment: I think the question is not worth to get answered here, expecially by a person at your reputation. Probably you can finish the same in a comment

Comment: @un-lucky - I agree this is a basic beginner's question and is unlikely to be useful to anyone else. However, just like you, I'm happy to help somebody. I don't see why a comment is more appropriate than an answer. My understanding is that comments are for clarification questions, not answers.

Comment: Sorry for such easy question. Thank you very much

Comment: But for some reason it doesnt allow me to view the project in a browser. It says that `there were errors building the project`

Comment: @Oleg - Press no, then read the visual studio output window. Or click `View\Error List`.